# Can't access a simple Ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

**Important:** I am **NOT** using EKS. I have installed this cluster via shell-script. Consider that it is fully-functioning.

I have a cluster running entirely on EC2 instances, and can't access a very simple ingress.

I have done the following:

1. Installed nginx-ingress-controller via helm-chart

```bash
$ helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
$ helm repo update
$ helm install nginx nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --create-namespace --namespace "nginx"
```

2. Created my Deployment, Service and Ingress in the **app1** namespace

**Deployment:**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deploy1
  namespace: app1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello1
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: hashicorp/http-echo
          name: hello1
          args:
            - "-text=\"Hello from application 1!\""
```

**Service:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc1
  namespace: app1
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello1
  ports:
    - protocol: 'TCP'
      port: 5678
      targetPort: 5678
  type: ClusterIP
```

**Ingress:**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress1
  namespace: app1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.alexthedeveloper.com.br
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/app1"
          backend:
            service:
              name: svc1
              port:
                number: 5678
```

3. Pointed my DNS record **app1.alexthedeveloper.com.br** to the worker-nodes IP's in Route 53

[image]

4. When trying to access **app1.alexthedeveloper.com.br/app1**, I get the following error:

[image]

Since the service is of type ClusterIP, I can curl it normally from inside the master node. Also I'm sure that port 80 is open in my security-group, and the cluster is in Amazon Linux 2 vanilla installation (did not change anything)

Please help!

Comment: Small comment to add: Please use the `ingressClassName` instead of the annotation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Contact your `nginx-ingress` `Service` by a `NodePort` (in this example `31111`) as the `curl` to a worker node ip address with port `80` won't work:

```bash
kubectl get svc -n nginx
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.111.12.216   <pending>     80:-->31111/TCP<--,443:32467/TCP   8m53s
```

---

#### Explanation:

Kubernetes [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) are handled differently when Kubernetes itself is a managed solution like (`GKE`, `AKS`, `EKS`) and non-managed solutions like the one you've created.

Assuming that you are using `EKS`, `nginx-ingress` would receive an address from `AWS` loadbalancer and you could contact it to access your `hello-world` app.

You would see that here:

```bash
kubectl get svc -n nginx
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.111.12.216   <pending>     80:31111/TCP,443:32467/TCP   8m53s
                                                      ^^^^^^
                                                       HERE!
```

Your setup is self-managed hence the output of this command will be similar to the one that I've included above. The access to your application can be fulfilled either by:

- Service of type `ClusterIP` with a name `svc1` and internal port:

  - `5678` (from inside of the cluster)
- Service of type `NodePort` of your `nginx-ingress` controller and the ports:

  - `31111`(HTTP) (from outside of the cluster) <-- will be different for your setup!
  - `32467`(HTTPS) (from outside of the cluster) <-- will be different for your setup!

Basically the external IP for a load balancer targeting your environment won't be assigned.

---

For this to work exactly as described on port `80` you would need to configure your `nginx-ingress` `Deployment` to use a `hostPort`. You would also need to consider what will happen if you have more than 1 `Node` and `nginx-ingress` controller will be recreated.

From best practices standpoint, I would advise against it and stick to a `NodePort`:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Configuration: Overview: Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#services)*

I believe you can find `AWS` solutions that could do the port forwarding for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s because of your rewrite. You’re rewriting your /app1 path to / and you have nothing serving on /

Comment out that line in your annotation, reapply and give it a go again.

(Sorry for poor formatting, posting on mobile)

Comment: I doubt that this is the issue considering the `hashicorp/http-echo` responds with a custom message with any path. Still the point that the rewrite should be fixed still stands.